# Lag in scrolling behavior on IE 10 and IE Edge modes

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, scrollbar, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to synchronize scrolling between two containers. But I see a lag in the scrolling of the synchronized one. Here is the fiddle for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/n9ryLdaw/2/

Sample Code snippet:

```
$('#box2').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#box1').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Note: This works fine in chrome and IE 9 as well but lags on IE 10 and IE Edge.

Has any one found a workaround for this?