# javascript synchronize scroll on ms edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, microsoft-edge

I use js to support the scrolling on a web-project.
It's working very fine, except on microsoft edge.

On edge it does scroll first the content of the page and a bit later it executes the scrolling from my js. I don't use preventDefault on the scroll function, because I don't scroll the whole content with my js.

I prepared a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uka3n63j/1/) which shows the problem. 
I also found this Question [Lag in scrolling behavior on IE 10 and IE Edge modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755614/lag-in-scrolling-behavior-on-ie-10-and-ie-edge-modes) which has the same problem, but don't got an answer. The author of the question has written this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/n9ryLdaw/2/) as example, which causes the same problem as I tried it.

Here is also the sample I prepared on JSFiddle:

```js
if($(window).width() >= 300) { 

  // scroll function
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {

  setDefaultOffsets();

        //e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation();
        //e.returnValue = false;

        var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
        localStorage.setItem('scrollTop', offset);

        $("#teaser").css({top: (TeaseDefaultTop - offset) + 'px'});

        if ((PreOffset - offset) <= SwitchPos) {
            $('#controlbar').css({top: SwitchPos + 'px'});
        } else {
            $('#controlbar').css({top: (PreOffset - offset) + 'px'});

        }

        return false;
    });

    $(function () {

  setDefaultOffsets();
        var previousOffset = localStorage.getItem('scrollTop');

        if (previousOffset > maxScrollOffset) {
            previousOffset = maxScrollOffset;
        }

        if (previousOffset > 100) {
            window.scroll(0, previousOffset);
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('#teaser').offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }, 500);

        }
    });

    $(window).scrollTop( 0.5 )
}

function setDefaultOffsets() {
 // difderent values for the different media querys
 if($(window).width() > 0) {
  maxScrollOffset = 100;
  TeaseDefaultTop = 101;
  PreOffset = 300;
  SwitchPos = 101;
 }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 500%;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 7;
}

#teaser {
 
  color: transparent;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/NwOWE.jpg); 
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 101px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
  }
  
  #controlbar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    position: fixed;
    top: 252px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  
  #content {
    margin-top: 350px;
  }
  
  #slogan {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(220, 140, 40, 0.6);
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 10%;
    padding: 10px;
    top:200px;
  }
  
   #demo1 {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(40, 140, 220, 0.8);
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;
    right: 10%;
    padding: 10px;
    top:300px;
  }
  
    #demo2 {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(140, 220, 40, 0.8);
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;
    right: 10%;
    padding: 10px;
    top:200px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<div id='header'>
Header with Menue, Logo and stuff
</div>
<div id='teaser'>
Teaser Image
</div>
<div id='slogan'>
A slogan or something else (just 3-10 words).
</div>
<div id='demo1'>
For demonstartion
</div>
<div id='demo2'>
For demonstartion
</div>
<div id='controlbar'>
Some Elements like Print, PDF Buttons, search form, breadcrumbs ....
</div>
<div id='content'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
</div>
```

```
   // Source of image and a bit of the code:
  // https://jsfiddle.net/0z8mvewo/
```

Does someone know a workaround/solution for this problem?

Edit:
It's really strange, that I can't find more informations about this problem anywhere. Could this problem occurs only on virtual machines?
I'm a mac user and my tests on microsoft edge were done in a virtual machine hosted on VMWare Fusion.
I tested the scrolling over the macbook pro touchpad and a normal logitech mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Your prepared JSFiddle doesn't work for me, but I took a look at the other fiddle with the two boxes.

First: There is no good way to do this. Change the specific behavior of the browser is never a good idea.

Second: I "hacked" it with an transparent layer above the two boxes. You can change it to a layer just over the right box if you like to.

Step 1) Wrap those boxes

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box1">...</div>
  <div id="box2">...</div>
</div>
```

Step 2) Insert another div within the wrapper. Add anonther div inside these added div.

```
<div id="scrollableOverlay"><div id="inScrollableOverlay"></div>
```

Step 3) Set the size to maximum and the overflow-property in the same way like the box you want to scroll. Furthermore make it transparent.

```
#scrollableOverlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Step 4) add some javascript to set the size for the content-div from Step 2 and attach the scroll event to it. If the event fires scroll both boxes at the same time.

```
$('#inScrollableOverlay').css('height', $('#box2').prop("scrollHeight"));
$('#scrollableOverlay').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#box1, #box2').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n9ryLdaw/3/

***But there is a new Problem: you cannot select text from the boxes because of the hidden layer before it. These solution is only practable if there is no need for such a user interaction!***

A better way would be the block the scroll event and trigger the scroll for both boxes at the same time, but this is not working at the time of writing because the scroll event is not preventable in ms edge.

Comment: Thank you for your clean answer.
I've seen that the snippin from my last post don't work on stackoverflow, but on the JSFiddle page it works for me. Your idea with the transparent area is pretty nice, but sadly I have content in that area which has to be clickable.

As I have seen, there are no more workarounds for this problem. I have to overthink the div-setting I use and create a solution where I don't scroll with js, or the opposite; to scroll everything with js (I start to hate edge :( ).